# How does ethereum store the 300k validator addresses

Tags: addresses, storage, beacon-chain

My question is possibly naive but since I am facing a similar problem, I would like to know how does ethereum really know which addresses are validator addresses without storing a 300k long array?

If it's done with some mapping I would also be curious to hear the details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a block explorer, you can see validators as those with valid deposits to the [deposit contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000219ab540356cbb839cbe05303d7705fa).

There's [over a billion transactions](https://etherscan.io/txs) on the chain so the number of validators is tiny in comparison. Each client will have their own format for storing these on your hard drive.

At the [client specification level](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#beacon-state), it is simply a list:

`validators: List[Validator, VALIDATOR_REGISTRY_LIMIT]`

Validators are appended as their [deposit is processed](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#deposits):

`state.validators.append(get_validator_from_deposit(deposit))`

Answer (score 0):

possibly they use merkle trees to store the details as storing tremendous amounts of data is very costly in blockchain

Answer (score 0):

The Ethereum 2.0 deposit contract uses [merkle tree](https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000219ab540356cbb839cbe05303d7705fa#code).